# Android, volley : When using volley, neither the Errorlistener nor the Responselistener is called

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am new in volley and android, I have installed the volley with gradle and done the same thing as the official tutorial. But there is no response, which means neither the Errorlistener nor the Responselistener is called.
Can you help me? My code is as follow:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fuck_view"
        />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TextView message = findViewById(R.id.fuck_view);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        String url = "http://www.google.com";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        message.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                message.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });

        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        queue.start();
       }
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.test">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this :

```java
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Result handling 
        System.out.println("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        // Error handling
        System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
        error.printStackTrace();

    }
});

// Add the request to the queue
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```